# What is the limit of the "restsums" of the harmonic series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I'm trying to determine the following limit:

$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{1}{k} $

I know that

$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k < \infty \implies \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=n}^\infty a_n = 0$,

which follows from Cauchy's convergence test. Considering the problem I'm working on right now, I would hope the first limit to be zero, too - even though the harmonic series diverges.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: $\sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{1}{k} = \infty$ for each $n$, so the limit is ...?

Comment: This is why Dominated Convergence requires the dominating function to be summable.

Comment: Another example is $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\frac1k$$ the terms tend to $0$, but the sum does not.

Comment: @MartinR I have thought about that way, too. Every element of the sequence is $\infty$, so the limit should be $\infty$, too, right? But there are constant sequences whose limits are different from that constant, such as $ a_n = \lceil 1/n \rceil  $.

Comment: @christophp: what limit do you get there? The limit of a constant sequence is always that constant. For example, the limit of that sequence is $1$.

Comment: @robjohn I figured zero, since 1/n tends to zero?

Comment: @christophp: you'd be figuring wrong, in that case.

Comment: @robjohn That was my counterexample all along. If that's wrong it would clear everything up. Thanks!

Comment: Consider the function $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)=1$ for $x\ne0$. What is $\lim\limits_{x\to0}f(x)$?

Comment: Right, I should have thought about continuity. Silly in retrospect, I wanted that sequence to converge too much :) it would have been very useful to me. Thank you very much!

Comment: For any $n>1$, $0<\frac1n<1$ so $\lceil \frac1n \rceil=1$. So although $\frac1n \rightarrow 0$, $\lceil \frac1n \rceil$ stays stuck at $1$ and can never be brought arbitrarily close to $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit doesn't exist since $$\sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{1}{k}$$is undefined for and $n\in \Bbb N$. Check the on [Harmonic series (mathematics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)) Wikipedia.